# Laravel: Ajax pass selected option on change to controller

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a select box in my View. What I want to do is, when I select an option in the select box, it will update the view with data fetched from database. Below is a snippet of my attempted codes:

View.php

```
< script >
  $('#examId').on('change', function() {
    var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var examid = optionSelected.val();
    alert(examid);

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/admin/testresults/show",
        data: {
          id: examid
        }
        // data: $("#examId").val()
      })
      .done(function() {
        alert('im here');
      });
  }); < /script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="testresults">
  <select name="examId" style="width:50%;" id="examId">
    <option value='non'>Select an exam...</option>
    <option value='1'>Foo1</option>
    <option value='2'>Foo2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

if(isset($rows)){ 
  $i=1; 
  foreach ($rows as $row) { 
    print "
      <tr>
        <td>".$i."</td>
        <td>".$row->name." ".$row->last_name."</td>
        <td>".($result = ($row->result == 1) ? 'Pass' : 'Fail')."</td>
      </tr>
    ";
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Controller.php

```
public function showTestResults(){
  $examId = Input::get('id');
  $rows = TestResults::getExamNamebyID($examId);
  return  View::make('backend.admin.testResults.index')->with('rows', $rows);
}
```

Route.php

```
Route::post('testresults/show',array('as' => 'show','uses' => 'AdminController@showTestResults'));
```

Model.php

```
public static function getExamResults($examId){
    return DB::table('testresults')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'testresults.userId')
        ->where('examId', $examId)
        ->groupBy('testresults.userId')
        ->get();
}
```

However, when i choose an option in the select box, I'm getting the following error:

> POST http://localhost:8000/admin/testresults/show 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

What should I change? Is my concept correct?
Thanks!

Comment: is your route correct ? do u hit on the `showTestResults` function ?

Comment: @K.Toress can u guide me on how can I check that?

Comment: just return something in that controller like `return "success";` and check you have get the same error or not ? dont forget to comment other things in the function. :)

Comment: @K.Toress  i tried to change the controller to return a view called hello...did not work

Comment: so the problem is with your routes please check the routes

Comment: Do any steps there depend on session, authentication, or cookies?  The .ajax wouldn't be sending any of that.

Comment: @Joe no...i'm not using any one of those

Comment: change your Route::post('testresults/show', ...) to Route::post('admin/testresults/show', ...), also check "php artisan route" on your console to see list of defined routes

Answer (score 2):

seems like your routing is not correct, so please try this one,

change your `view.php` in to a blade file, to do that rename the `view.php` into `view.blade.php`

**in your `view` file,**

replace

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="testresults">
```

with

```
Form::open(array('route' => 'show', 'name' => 'form1', 'id' => 'testForm', 'method' => 'POST'))
```

or

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="{{ URL::route('show') }}" id="testForm">
```

**in your `js`,**

```
....
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: $("#testForm").attr('action'),
    data: {
      id: examid
    }
    // data: $("#examId").val()
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert('im here');
});
....
```

Comment: doesn't work, it says link_to_route() does not exist